# New Finder window opens maximized every time

Tags: finder, macos

For some reason, now every time I start Finder or ask for a new window, it occupies my entire screen (note this is **not full screen mode**, it is just normal screen mode but the Finder is resized maximally to fit the entire visible area, except the bar at the top).

I tried resizing this Finder window and closing, then restarting but end up getting a new Finder window that is resized occupying my entire workspace.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Running Yosemite latest on MBP retina 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is usually caused by the preference, you can try to remove the plist file temporarily. This file is in the directory `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

Answer (score 5):

Open a new window, resize it, then immediately close it. That tells Finder to remember the new size for all new windows. No need to throw away *all* of your preferences just to change one.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.